# Knockout JS href attr not binding on .NET MVC4 partial page

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I am a moderate Knockout user, but this is my first time using it in an MVC4 environment. All of the usual bindings have been working properly, but I am running into an issue where my href attribute binding does not seem to be firing when I load and then bind a partial view.

Here is my partial view markup:

```
<div id="quick-panel">
    <a class="icon-set" data-bind="attr: { href: Contact.fullEditUrl() }" >&#x1F4DD;</a>
</div>

<div id="rightbarcontent">
....
</div>

<script>
ko.applyBindings(window.contact.viewmodel, document.getElementById("rightbarcontent"));
</script>
```

And here is my viewmodel snippet where I define Contact.fullEditUrl():

```
window.contact.Contact = function (data) {
    var contact = this;
    this.id = ko.observable(data.id);
    this.fullEditUrl = ko.computed(function() {
        return "http://localhost:24191/contact/contactfulledit/" + data.id;
    });
}
```

I fire the namespaced binding after the DOM has been loaded. All of my other bindings on the same page (about 20 of them) are all correct, but the href never gets set for my anchor tag, and I'm not really sure why. I've double-checked my syntax on various sites and threads, and it seems to be correct

Comment: Hmm, the code you've posted [seems to be working](http://jsfiddle.net/jeroenheijmans/Eyhyx/). Perhaps the issue is some other bit?

Comment: Have you set this up as a view model, and used the `applyBindings`? show all your JS code.

Comment: Thank you christiandev. After looking back at where I call applyBindings, I noticed that I was targeting my applyBindings to a specific div, and my anchor tags were outside of that div. Edit will show the full markup and code for explanation

Answer (score 0):

you want this.id() instead of data.id()

Id also suggest you make it

```
window.contact.Contact = function (data) {
   var contact = this;
   contact.id = ko.observable(data.id);
   contact.fullEditUrl = ko.computed(function() {
       return "http://localhost:24191/contact/contactfulledit/" + contact .id();
   });
}
```

And if the id never changes (which it doesn't look like it does you don't have to use any observable or computed's at all:

```
window.contact.Contact = function (data) {
   var contact = this;
   contact.id = data.id;
   contact.fullEditUrl = "http://localhost:24191/contact/contactfulledit/" + contact.id
}
```

You only need to use observable when something is changing that you need to keep track of.

As far as the partial part goes. Is the partial contained in the main context (what you bound in the ko.applyBindings)? Because if it is not, then ko won't be able to find it.

I would suggest that you wrap everything in another div and bind to that.

But also, if you already have something bound on your main page that this is contained inside of. Then applying the bindings again will fail. In this case I would suggest that you do one of two things:

1) Combine them into the same bindings context. 
2) Make sure that your bindings in your main page and your partial do not overlap. Overlapping bindings will cause them to fail.